# Polynomial-time algorithm for uniformly sampling the $n$-slice of a context-free language

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, formal-languages

Let $L\subset \Sigma^*$ be a context-free language. The $n$-slice is the intersection $L\cap \Sigma^n$ for a non-negative integer $n$.

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for uniformly sampling from the $n$-slice of a context-free language?

A quasipolynomial time algorithm is presented in "[A Quasi-Polynomial-Time Algorithm for Sampling Words from a Context-Free Language](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1006/inco.1997.2621)".

Comment: So, do you ask for an improvement over an existing research paper in MO answer? Why do you think such an improvement exists at first place?

Comment: This question is more suitable for cstheory.stackexchange.com